# php remove duplicate subarray from array and count them

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of arrays that hold 4 fields, i want to remove all subarrays that have same first 3 values and sum their 4th value. Please help.

```
$a = [
       ["123", "XL", "blue", 1],
       ["345", "L", "black", 1],
       ["534", "S", "white", 2],
       ["345", "L", "black", 4]
     ]
$a = fixArray($a);
```

after

```
$a = [
       ["123", "XL", "blue", 1],
       ["345", "L", "black", 5],
       ["534", "S", "white", 2]
     ]
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function FixArray($arr)
{
    // create a copy to work with
    $ca = $arr; 

    // we're gonna fill this one and return it
    $cr = array();

    for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){

        $tmp = $arr[$i];

        for($j=0; $j<count($arr); $j++){

            // empty the same element in the copy so we don't double count it.
            if($i == $j){
                $ca[$j][0] = "";
                $ca[$j][1] = "";
                $ca[$j][2] = "";
                $ca[$j][3] = "";
            }

            if($tmp[0] == $ca[$j][0] && $tmp[1] == $ca[$j][1] && $tmp[2] == $ca[$j][2]){
                // if matched, add then push into the return array then empty the element from the copy
                array_push($cr, [$ca[$j][0], $ca[$j][1], $ca[$j][2], ($ca[$j][3] + $tmp[3])]);
                $ca[$j][0] = "";
                $ca[$j][1] = "";
                $ca[$j][2] = "";
                $ca[$j][3] = "";                    
            }           
        }   
    }

    return $cr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See inline comments for explanation of method.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ee7cbca1fc570f87c553e27843ea07c5bad7e54))

```
$a=[
   ["123", "XL", "blue", 1],
   ["345", "L", "black", 1],
   ["534", "S", "white", 2],
   ["345", "L", "black", 4]
];

function merge_sum($array){
    foreach($array as $a){
        $tmp_key=implode('_',array_slice($a,0,3));  // generate temporary key from first three elements in row
        if(!isset($result[$tmp_key])){
            $result[$tmp_key]=$a;  // instantiate the unique row
        }else{
            $result[$tmp_key][3]+=$a[3];  // sum the new quantity and the old quantity
        }
    }
    return array_values($result);  // reindex the rows (remove the temporary keys)
}

var_export(merge_sum($a));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '123',
    1 => 'XL',
    2 => 'blue',
    3 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '345',
    1 => 'L',
    2 => 'black',
    3 => 5,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '534',
    1 => 'S',
    2 => 'white',
    3 => 2,
  ),
)
```